# Как получить значение из БД (sqlite3)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, telebot, sqlite3

Хочу получить значение общего литража сколько пользователь выпил.
Команда, бот, и база данных правильно работает, но вот пытался создать чтобы получало общий литраж выпитой жидкости, но что-то намудрил и получилась полная лажа.
**Команда в bot.py**

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['energydrink', 'энергетик'], chat_type=[types.ChatType.SUPERGROUP, types.ChatType.GROUP])
async def drinkenergy(message: types.Message):
    #tmpconnect = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    #tmpcursor = tmpconnect.cursor()

    number = random.uniform(1, 5)
    number = float('{:.1f}'.format(number))

    #tmpcursor.execute("UPDATE users SET number = number + ? WHERE user_id = ?", (number, user_id))

    #total_liters = db.get_totalenergetik(message.from_user.id, number) # эта фигня не работает

    db.add_energetik(number, message.from_user.id)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'@{message.from_user.username}, ты выпил(а) {number} л. энергетика.\nВыпито всего: {total_liters} л.', reply_markup=deletemarkup)
```

**Код db.py**

```
import sqlite3
import time

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))
            
    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.connection.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`) VALUES (?)", (user_id,))

    def add_energetik(self, number, user_id):
            with self.connection:
                return self.connection.execute("UPDATE `users` SET `number` = `number` + ? WHERE `user_id` = ?", (number, user_id,))
                self.connection.commit()

    def get_totalenergetik(self, user_id, number):
            with self.connection:
                return self.cursor.execute("SELECT `number` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?;", (user_id, number,))
```

Команда должна выдавать общее количество выпитой жидкости пользователя.
Переменная которая у меня не работает как я хочу:

```
total_liters = db.get_totalenergetik(message.from_user.id, number) # эта фигня не работает
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка:

```py
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.
```

UPD:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['energydrink', 'энергетик'], chat_type=[types.ChatType.SUPERGROUP, types.ChatType.GROUP])
async def drinkenergy(message: types.Message):
    #tmpconnect = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    #tmpcursor = tmpconnect.cursor()

    number = random.uniform(1, 5)
    number = float('{:.1f}'.format(number))

    #tmpcursor.execute("UPDATE users SET number = number + ? WHERE user_id = ?", (number, user_id))

    total_liters = db.get_totalenergetik(message.from_user.id, number)

    db.add_energetik(number, message.from_user.id)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'@{message.from_user.username}, ты выпил(а) {number} л. энергетика.\nВыпито всего: {total_liters} л.', reply_markup=deletemarkup)
```

Comment: Что возвращает `total_liters = db.get_totalenergetik(message.from_user.id, number)`?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin он возвращает значение сколько литров выпил пользователь за все время.

Comment: Вы написали, что работает не так, как ожидалось. В чем проблема?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, когда я пишу команду все работает, вот только консоль выдает ошибку и бот крашится, из-за того что я что-то сделал не правильно в db.py, а именно там где всего выпито литров пользователем. В bd.py я подписал как `def get_totalenergetik(self, user_id, number):`.
А в самой команде `total_liters = db.get_totalenergetik(message.from_user.id, number)`

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin ошибка очень большая, и команда не отправляется.
https://pastebin.com/nKNirVNb
Я думаю ему что-то не нравится тут: `File "C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\bot\bot.py", line 57, in drinkenergy
    total_liters = db.get_totalenergetik(message.from_user.id, number)`
`И тут File "C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\bot\db.py", line 25, in get_totalenergetik
    return self.cursor.execute("SELECT 'number' FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id' = ?;", (user_id, number,))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.`

Comment: @ClarkDevlin залил на imgur, чтобы было легче читать: https://imgur.com/hnNFuaM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас сразу несколько ошибок, отметил их знаками `#`.

В функции `add_user` не происходит добавление пользователя в базу данных, т.к, нет сохранения изменений с помощью `connection.commit()`. В функции `add_energetik` не срабатывает обновление данных в базе, т.к, `return` выходит из функции не доходя до `connection.commit()`.

Непосредственно ошибка, которую вы приложили, возникает в функции `get_totalenergetik` из-за того, что в запросе у вас 1 плейсхолдер, но передаете вы 2 аргумента. Аргумент `number` лишний. Так же не было `.fetchall()`, функция возвращала объект базы данных, а не значение.

```py
import sqlite3
import time

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))
            
    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`) VALUES (?)", (user_id,))
            self.connection.commit() ###

    def add_energetik(self, number, user_id):
            with self.connection:
                self.cursor.execute("UPDATE `users` SET `number` = `number` + ? WHERE `user_id` = ?", (number, user_id,))
                self.connection.commit() ###

    def get_totalenergetik(self, user_id):
            with self.connection:
                return self.cursor.execute("SELECT `number` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?;", (user_id, )).fetchall() ### UPD
```

UPD:

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=['energydrink', 'энергетик'], chat_type=[types.ChatType.SUPERGROUP, types.ChatType.GROUP])
async def drinkenergy(message: types.Message):
    #tmpconnect = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    #tmpcursor = tmpconnect.cursor()
    number = random.uniform(1, 5)
    number = float('{:.1f}'.format(number))
    #tmpcursor.execute("UPDATE users SET number = number + ? WHERE user_id = ?", (number, user_id))
    total_liters = db.get_totalenergetik(message.from_user.id) # здесь был лишний аргумент
    db.add_energetik(number, message.from_user.id)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'@{message.from_user.username}, ты выпил(а) {number} л. энергетика.\nВыпито всего: {total_liters[0]} л.', reply_markup=deletemarkup)
```

Comment: сделал как вы сказали, вылезла ошибка в консоли ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

Comment: На какой строчке? И весь текст ошибки желательно.

Comment: Это что-то уже с командой:

Comment: Команду написал в вопросе там где текст UPD:

Comment: На какой строчке ошибка? И что выведет `print(total_liters)`

Comment: print(total_liters) вообще мне кажется ничего не вывел: https://imgur.com/A5R87ak

Comment: @Riktik обновил ответ

Comment: Все равно ошибка:
`File "C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\bot\db.py", line 26, in get_totalenergetik
    return self.cursor.execute("SELECT 'number' FROM 'users' WHERE'`user_id' = ?;", (user_id)).fetchall() ###`
`ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type`

Comment: @Riktik обновил функцию `get_totalenergetik`

Comment: Заработало,  только теперь по бокам цифр из переменной вот так @riktik_official, ты выпил(а) 4.7 л. энергетика.
Выпито всего: **[(9.0,)]** л. UPD: ещё нужно чтобы одна цифра после запятой была

Comment: @Riktik поправил код, если ответ Вам помог, то пометьте его, как правильный. Если остались вопросы - создайте новый вопрос.